# Compare every cell in a dataframe with its surrounding cells

Tags: python, dataframe, networkx

I have a dataframe similar to this yet, but a lot bigger (3000x3000):

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **W** | 3 | 1 | 8 | 3 | 4 |
| **X** | 2 | 2 | 9 | 1 | 1 |
| **Y** | 5 | 7 | 1 | 3 | 7 |
| **Z** | 6 | 8 | 5 | 8 | 9 |

where the [A,B,C,D,E] are the column names and [W,X,Y,Z] are the rows indexs.

I want to compare every cell with its surrounding cells. If the cell has a greater value than its neighbor cell value, create a directed edge (using networkX package) from that cell to its smaller value neighbor cell. For example:
examining cell (X,B), we should add the following:
G.add_edge((X,B), (W,B))  and G.add_edge((X,B), (Y,C)) and so on for every cell in the dataframe.

Currently I am doing it using two nested loops. However this takes hours to finish and a lot of resources (RAM).

**Is there any more efficient way to do it?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have edges in a networkx graph, then you will not be able to avoid the nested for loop.

The comparison is actually easy to optimize. You could make four copies of your matrix and shift each one step into each direction. You are then able to vectorize the comparison by a simple df > df_copy for every direction.
Nevertheless, when it comes to creating the edges in your graph, it is necessary for you to iterate over both axes.

My recommendation is to write the data preparation part in Cython. Also have a look at graph-tools which at its core is written in C++. With that much edges you will probably also get performance issues in networkx itself.